# Why can there be an ArrayOutOfBounds Exception when you are opening a file in java using FileInputStream?

Tags: java, exception, io, inputstream, indexoutofboundsexception

Why is there a need to check ArrayIndexOutOfBounds in FileInputStream in java? This same code is given as an example in a book for core java.

```
FileInputStream fis;
try{
    //fis=new FileInputStream("inputFIle.txt");       
    fis=new FileInputStream(argv[0]);
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println("File was not found");
}catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: There can't. That's just a really bad example, as far as I can see - assuming you've reproduced it accurately.

Comment: Perhaps the try block in the original code contains other method calls that may throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. The code you posted doesn't pass compilation.

Comment: @Eran Yes it does. It's an unchecked exception.

Comment: @user2025949 Please provide a proper citation: author, title, edition, chapter, and page.

Comment: @EJP You are correct about `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` being unchecked. However, the posted code contains `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`. I don't know what that is :)

Comment: @Eran : you were correct. I had written it wrong.

Comment: @EPJ : this code is from the book 'Java 2 complete reference (5th edition) from 216 industry' page no. 325 and page no. 326 and title being: Reading and writing from files

Comment: **NO IT IS NOT** I took the trouble to check this. The original code uses `argv[0]` for the filename instead of your misspelt string literal, and obviously an array reference can throw that exception. You have misquoted the text you are relying on. Downvoted and voted to close as mere typo.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need. If you look up the documentation for FileInputStream:

> Constructor Detail
>
> **FileInputStream**
> *public FileInputStream(String name)*
> *throws FileNotFoundException*
>
> Creates a FileInputStream by opening a connection to an actual file, the file >named by the path
> name name in the file system. A new FileDescriptor object is created
> to represent this file connection. First, if there is a security
> manager, its checkRead method is called with the name argument as its
> argument.
>
> If the named file does not exist, is a directory rather than a regular
> file, or for some other reason cannot be opened for reading then a
> FileNotFoundException is thrown.
>
> Parameters: name - the system-dependent file name. Throws:
>
> *FileNotFoundException* - if the file does not exist, is a directory
> rather than a regular file, or for some other reason cannot be opened
> for reading.
>
> *SecurityException* - if a security manager exists and its
> checkRead method denies read access to the file.

That constructor does not throw ArrayIndexOutOfBounds. May be it was just a small example written to show syntax or had some other code in the try block.

Answer (score 0):

> This same code is given as an example in a book for core java.

## NO IT IS NOT

I took the trouble to check this. The original code uses `argv[0]` for the filename instead of your misspelt string literal, and obviously an array reference can throw that exception. You have misquoted the text you are relying on.

Comment: @EPJ so you think that a file name as a string-argument can't be given as an input to FileInputStream constructor? My code is similar to this code and i just asked - why there was a need to check exception of ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

Comment: and, i don't think helping someone is a trouble if you have to take.

Comment: Of course a filename can be passed as a string to `FileInputStream`. That's what both your code code and the code in the book do. At this point I don't care what you think. I object to wasting my time because you changed the code, and did not say so, and misled everybody for a week, and created a completely false impression of the book; and I do not appreciate downloading a large PDF and flipping to page 325-6, only to find out that you're not telling the truth. And finally, when you changed the code, you also changed the possible exceptions that can be thrown. Surely this is obvious?

Comment: @EPJ : You know what-now i got the answer. I DID MY MISTAKE but you could not give the correct answer. The actual reason to include the ArrayOutOfBoundException was that the book used argv[] ARRAY which could throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception. This is what was expected from you . Not a  "-1" on my question.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points to upload an image/screenshot. That is the reason- you had to download the pdf. Although, I APPRECIATE that you took the burden to download the pdf. Thanks anyway, that you made me find the mistake.

Comment: I do not intend to be misrepresented by you. Yet again you are not telling the truth. **My answer is up there in black and white:** 'the original code uses argv[0] for the filename instead of your misspelt string literal, and obviously an array reference can throw that exception'. Really this is all quite shocking. I had already compained, justifiably, that the entire question was a wild goose chase because of your inaccuracy with your sources, and here you are doing it again. Next time, read, and quote, and attribute, accurately.

Comment: And I don't know what this nonsense about uploading an image is about. You seem to regard your misquotations as problems for other  people to solve. They aren't. All you had to do was quote your source correctly, or indeed read it correctly in the first place: then none of this would have occurred. Work on it. It's a weakness.

Answer (score 0):

The possibility of explicitly catching an *ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException* in *FileInputStream* is only **when you give the input to FileInputStream Constructor in the form of an array value like arg[0]**. Because, it is quite possible that in the command line , you might have given only one argument but you are trying to access argv[1] or argv[2].